# Line Breaks in Categorical Axis Labels, Bokeh Plots

Tags: python-2.7, formatting, bokeh

Below is a simple example of a plot I have where there are categorical axes with long labels.

```python
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

x_labs = [
    "Long Tick Label That Needs Line Breaks",
    "Longer Tick Label That Needs Line Breaks", 
    "Even Longer Tick Label That Needs Line Breaks"
    ]
y_labs = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]

x = [x_lab for __ in range(len(x_labs)) for x_lab in x_labs] 
y = ["foo", "foo", "foo", "bar", "bar", "bar", "baz", "baz", "baz"]

colors = [
    "#0B486B", "#79BD9A", "#CFF09E",
    "#79BD9A", "#0B486B", "#79BD9A",
    "#CFF09E", "#79BD9A", "#0B486B"
    ]

p = figure(x_range=x_labs, y_range=y_labs)
p.rect(x, y, color=colors, width=1, height=1)
show(p)
```

The x-axis labels overlap, so I'd like to insert line breaks. I cannot figure out how to do this. I have tried adding `'\n'`, `'\\n'`, `'<br>'` between words but that has not worked.

There are reasons why I do not want to change the labels to shorter strings, increase the glyph size, rotate the axis labels, or use another plotting package. So, I really just want to know if I can add line breaks to tick labels in bokeh.

I am using bokeh version 0.10.0.

Thanks much.

Comment: Do you have any update on a solution to this?  I have tried \n, \r\n, <br> to break up ticklabels and titles without success.

Answer (score -1):

A line break in DOS based systems is Ascii 13,10

This can be represented by the sequence `\r\n`

Comment: This does not work. I changed the first tick label from `"Long Tick Label That Needs Line Breaks"` to `"Long Tick Label\r\nThat Needs Line Breaks"` and it does not result in a line break in the plot (in fact, adding `\r\n` appears to only added an extra space). Also, I am on a Unix system, I don't know that this is relevant though since bokeh plots are html files and rendered in the browser.

Comment: @cpsempek Sorry about that, then it does seem that <br > would be better.  Try it with spaces after the 'r' and after the closing brace.

Comment: I have scanned the reference http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.10.0/docs/reference.html and perhaps it is not supported yet (Not exposed yet)...Seems strange for such a powerful library